# Denying Keycloak Authentication based on Google Account Attribute

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, keycloak, openid-connect, google-account

The System consists of a Keycloak 16.0.0 instance and uses Google as an Identity Provider. I want to fail the authentication based on an attribute that is given inside of the google account information.

The JSON from the google API (GET [https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}](https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/%7BuserKey%7D)) looks like this:

```
{
    "kind": "admin#directory#user",
    "id": "00000000",
    "etag": "xxxx",
    "primaryEmail": "test@test.mail.com",
    "name": {
      "givenName": "User",
      "familyName": "Test",
      "fullName": "User Test"
    },
..........
..........
..........
..........
    "organizations": [
      {
        "name": "Organization5"
      }
    ]
  }
```

After a user logs in through the SSO Google Login, a user in keycloak should only be created when he is in "Organization5".

I tried using a custom script in the default "First Broker Login" flow before the "Create User If Unique(create unique user config)" execution. But I cannot get the keycloak access token from the identity because the identity is not initalized yet.

Is there any easy out-of-the-box solution that I am missing?